# How to delete a docker image based on a pattern and timestamp together

Tags: docker, grep, timestamp, docker-image

I have been trying to delete the docker images based on a pattern and a given timestamp, using grep command to search for a pattern and including filter command with until, so that I'd get the docker images deleted based on the given requirements. For a reference the command I used:

```
docker images -a | grep "<pattern>" | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Above command is working but I want to delete a docker images based on some pattern as above but I need to include a timestamp into it to be more specific, using this filter command:

```
--filter"until<timestamp>"
```

Comment: Timestamp from what? Of the moment you delete? Or a timestamp on the image?

Comment: @BertC timestamp before the creation of the image, for example `--filter"until=10m"` will filter out all the images created before 10 minutes. Like that

Comment: With "docker inspect imageID" (output is a JSON) you can get the exact creation date of an image. Do that for all your images and detect which dates are older than given date. Would be a nice Bash script to write :-)

Comment: Thankyou @BertC gonna look into it :)